# Team Developer 2005.1 - Into Variable Always Empty

Tags: guptateamdeveloper

We are handling a legacy code which based on Team Developer 2005.1

There is a query like

```
  !!CB!! 70
Set sSqlCommand = '
            SELECT  name, value
            INTO    :sName, :sValue
            FROM    av_system_settings
            WHERE   name LIKE \'Company_\%\''
If NOT SqlPrepareAndExecute( hSqlMain, sSqlCommand )
    Return FALSE
Loop
    If SqlFetchNext( hSqlMain, nFetch )
    ...
```

Here the into variable `:sName, :sValue` are Strings but it always have empty value although the record has been looped correctly through `SqlFetchNext`

The into variable on other place are all fine. Just not working here one place.

Have run out of brain on this... Any idea? Guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For testing, you can use SqlImmediate(sSqlCommand ) instead of sqlprepareandexecute( ). If sName and sValue have value after 
    executing sqlImmediate means sql working fine.
2. Make sure SqlConnect() function returns true value.  If it returns false then make sure database creditionals are correct.
3. If the sValue variable need to hold  Long data then please have a look on  SqlSetLongBindDatatype ( ) function.
4. Check the value of  sql handle hsqlMain, if  it have a postive value or one it means that handle connected properly. Otherwise 
    if the handle value is null or zero, it means handle not connected.
5. Try to use SqlFetchRow ( hsqlMain, nRow, nFetch ) and increment the value of nRow by 1 till function return false or the value of nFetch becomes FETCH_EOF.

   `Set nRow = 0
   While (TRUE)
     If not SqlFetchRow( hsqlMain, nRow, nFetch )
        Break
     Set nRow = nRow + 1`

Comment: It turns out that the issue was caused by case #3 in answer: the data field is longer than 254 but `String` variable type were used with INTO... After changing them to `Long String`, it's working now. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped!. Please, consider accepting the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check nFetch after SqlFetchNext to be sure a record was found.

If nFetch  = FETCH_Ok , a record was found. 
So try calling SqlVarSetup(hSqlMain) before the SqlFetchNext , so the into vars have context.
Also try qualifying the into vars e.g. :hWndForm.frmTest.sName .

If nFetch  = FETCH_EOF , no record was found .